# permalinks url with woocommerce

Tags: permalinks, woocommerce-offtopic, url-rewriting, site-url

I have noticed that when i navigate to a product in my woocommerce site the URL is

```
https://mydomain.co.uk/product/procrastination-facebook-font-parody-graphic-quality-t-shirt-tee-mens-unisex/
```

and for the category it is:

```
https://mydomain.co.uk/product-category/t-shirts/mensunisex-t-shirts/social-networking/
```

How do i get rid of the /product and /product-category parts of the uRL

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's not advised to do this because it makes your WordPress work hard to find the correct page. And in some cases it may produce the incorrect page because it will always looks for posts and pages first. The 'product' and 'product-category' tags tell your WordPress it should be checking those specific post types for the correct content and nowhere else.
https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/removing-product-product-category-or-shop-from-the-urls/

As the article above states, some SEO plugins allow you to change or remove these if you really wish to give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

You can change this from permalink setting from admin panel.You will find woocommerce option at permalink menu in setting->permalinks in wordpress admin panel

Comment: I have tried that, and what i have got is the best i can do, other options are dates and such but they do not really work for woocommmerce

Comment: Do you see special block of woocommerce?